# AttributeError: module 'pygame.font' has no attribute 'Sysfont',

Tags: python, pygame

I just started Python and i thought to learn it using a tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-__8Xw9KTM

I'm following the tutorial step by step, however, it shows that i have an issue. Despite that I have word for word

Can someone help me?

[This is the part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8x3J.png)
[This is the tutorial's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIoPq.png)

Note: I have the `pygame.font.init()` included

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and  [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: 26.46 of the video, btw

Comment: None of us will watch the video. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok, I didn't know about that, I'm kinda new to this

Comment: Read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo. Python is case sensitive. `Sysfont` has to be [`SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont):

<s>`main_font = pygame.font.Sysfont("comicsans", 50)`</s>

```py
main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)
```

<s>`lost_font = pygame.font.Sysfont("comicsans", 60)`</s>

```py
lost_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 60)
```